# May be a mistake in Metaprogramming Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am reading *Metaprogramming Ruby* by ***Paolo Perrotta*** and I must say there is a mistake in the book,the following is the ruby code from page 70 of this book and I will past the code here again

```
class Computer
  def initialize(computer_id, data_source)
    @id = computer_id
    @data_source = data_source
  end
  def self.define_component(name)
    define_method(name) {
      info = @data_source.send "get_#{name}_info" , @id
      price = @data_source.send "get_#{name}_price" , @id
      result = "#{name.to_s.capitalize}: #{info} ($#{price})"
      return "* #{result}" if price >= 100
      result
    }
  end
  define_component :mouse
  define_component :cpu
  define_component :keyboard
```

`Computer.define_component` is a class method like static method in Java. What Java told us is that a static method can never access an instance attribute or an instance method without an object. So,`define_component` method must not use invoke define_method,which is an instance method. Logically speaking,class method was invoked before object have been created,so there is no way that `@data_source` and `@id` can be initialized(it have bean created). But here `define_component` invoked `define_method` without an instance. Is that correct?

Comment: FYI, English sentences start with a capital letter, and there should be a space (or some other white character) after a punctuation mark. Besides that, I cannot parse your sentences. And, there does not seem to be any question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your thinking is corrupted by java. It is a strict language with strict rules. Ruby is more powerful/flexible.

```
def self.define_component(name)
  # class scope here
  define_method(name) {
    # instance scope here. You can use instance-level instance variables.
  }
end
```

`define_component` method defines an **instance** method on the class. In the body of that instance method you, naturally, can use instance variables.

Comment: Not to mention, that you still could use instance variables in a class context (which are then scopes on the class's [eigenclass](http://madebydna.com/all/code/2011/06/24/eigenclasses-demystified.html).)

Comment: I do not think it make sence,the define_component need to be invoked when the class be created,but the method define_method it invokes will only be successful when class instance be create.So,when the define_component execute and succeed.

Comment: `define_method` (inside of `define_component`) accepts a block. It doesn't execute that right away. Instead it creates a regular instance method, which can be called later. See @akagr's answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the point slightly. The `define_method` will indeed not have access to the instance variables, but `define_method` when called on class will actually create a regular instance method. The name of this method is the parameter to define_method and the body of this new instance method is the block passed.

So define method will not actually execute the code (it can't). It will simply create a new method that can be called upon to execute the code.

I hope I got the point across.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby doesn't have static methods. The only similarity between Ruby class methods and Java static methods is that they can both be called on classes.

In Ruby, classes are objects — they are instances of a class named Class, and they can have their own instance variables just like other object can. A class method isn't like a static method in Java — it's a singleton method of the class. You can define instance-specific methods on any object in exactly the same way.

Comment: but the instance attribute does not bean initialized when the class method was invoked

Comment: Sure classes can have instance variables, but that's not what's happening here. Here the instance variables actually do belong to an instance of the `Computer` class. So none of this is relevant to the question.

Comment: @sepp2k: It isn't relevant to ssj's *precise situation*, but it is relevant to *the question*. The question was on the difference between Java static methods and Ruby class methods, and specifically the fact that Java static methods have no self/this. I was explaining how the languages are different here. The other answers already dealt with the fact that we were in an instance method, but did not address the question of whether there is a `self` in class methods and what implications it has, so I was answering that.